# how return a variable from a function and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component in which I have a button. I want to print a JSON string on click of that button. But whenever I try to return something it gives an error.

My component:

```
const emp_details= (props) => {

  function getdata(data){
    //console.log('button clicked');

   console.log(data);
    let result = data.reduce((r,c) => 
  (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r, {})

    const json = {emp_details : result};
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

   return JSON.stringify(json);

  }

return (

      <div>
        <button onClick= {getdata(props.details)}>Display </button>

      </div>

    );

  };

export default ShoppingCart;
```

I get this error:

Invariant Violation: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

How should I display the JSON result? 
I expect to see an output on the screen not on the console. So, after I click the button, it should display the output inside a  tag or something.

```
emp_details: {
//json string of the state
}
```

Comment: You have to make a variable to hold this data, make a UI element to show it, and connect the two with React's data binding. It's a completely different problem from the question that you've asked and that multiple people have answered correctly.

Comment: Hi user8306074! Just following-up, let me know if you have any questions, I know we had a discussion yesterday on how to integrate this. If you found my answer successful, would you please consider marking it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are invoking your `getdata()` as soon as the component renders. To work around this you want to pass an anonymous function to your event-listener which will call this function when the event actually occurs.

```
  <div>
    <button onClick= {() => getdata(props.details)}>Display</button>

  </div>
```

To get the data to display inside the component after clicking the button, we need to employ some sort of state-management to force the component to re-render.

Let's consider the following-code:

### Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import ShoppingCart from "./ShoppingCart";

const details = [
  {
    emp_code: "a001",
    company_code: "company_a",
    name: "abx",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "b002",
    company_code: "company_b",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "a002",
    company_code: "company_a",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "b003",
    company_code: "company_b",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ShoppingCart details={details} />
    </div>
  );
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So in the code above we pass in data as property called details to ShoppingCart.

### ShoppingCart.js

```
import React from "react";

import { useState } from "react";

const ShoppingCart = props => {
  //this gives us a state-value and state-updating function in that order. We passed in a default value of ""
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState({});
  function getdata(data) {
    let result = data.reduce(
      (r, c) =>
        (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r,
      {}
    );

    console.log(result);
    //create our data object and then update our state-value, forcing our component to re-render
    setCompanies(result);
  }

  //this creates a mark-up. It will get called again when we get an updated companies state value.
  const createMarkup = () => {
    //we're going to use the updated companies state-value now
    let markup = Object.entries(companies).map(
      ([companyName, array], index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{companyName}:</p>
            {array.map((emp, empIndex) => {
              return <p key={empIndex}>{emp}</p>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    );
    return markup;
  };

  return (
    //createMarkup() will be executed on re-render to display our markup
    <div>
      <div>{createMarkup()}</div>
      <button onClick={() => getdata(props.details)}>Display </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShoppingCart;
```

We pass in the data stored in props.detail as the argument for getData(). getData() will parse it to the structure we need and give us a result back. Then we store that result in our hook-state.

When the component re-renders we call createMarkup() thus giving us the JSX that includes all our companies and employee information.

Comment: it doesnt display anything. It doesnt give that error but doesnt display anthing

Comment: @user8306074 what do you want to display? The output from getData()? It sounds like you want to console.log() the result?

Comment: I want to display the output of "JSON.stringify(json);" on the my website not on the console.

Comment: @user8306074. Gotcha, well to produce something even remotely similar to that, we would need to have the component re-render. Why? Because the data isn't provided until you click on a button and we somehow need to tell the component to refresh with that data. We would need to employ component-state or a hooks. Is that something you would be interested in doing?

Comment: Oh, I see, but I am not familiar with hooks. Cant we return the output into a variable and then display that variable inside the return function itself?

Comment: We could do that, but the component will never re-render to display the updated variable, which is precisely why we need something like hooks to force our component to do so :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193740/discussion-between-user8306074-and-christopher-ngo).

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `onClick` not to the function `getdata` but the value returned by the function `getdata`.

Use a wrapper function all call function in that when you need pass arguments to function.

```
<button onClick= {() => getdata(props.details)}>Display </button>
```

Comment: But it doesnt display anything. It doesnt give that error but doesnt display anthing

Answer (score 1):

```
function Emp_details(props) {
    function getdata(){
    console.log(props.details);
    }
  return <div><button onClick= {getdata}>Display </button></div>

}



ReactDOM.render(<Emp_details details = "John Doe"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: you have to make getdata function accessible.
Hope you wont be getting syntax error.

Comment: I tried the above method, it doesnt give me error but fails to generate the output on the website which I want.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't help you. Please add your full component code.

Comment: this is my full code, I have a functional component

Comment: I have modified my answer, current not giving error and printing details in console for now.

Comment: I see the console.log works for me as well. However, if I'm unable to display the values on the web page.